# Is it possible to make a join between tables that are in different databases?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have two databases, one is oracle and the other one is postgres, and I need to perform a join select between tables in those databases. Is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: Hi Rodirgo Luz, welcome to stack overflow, It looks duplicated, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896524/join-data-from-2-oracle-tables-located-in-different-database-on-the-same-server

Comment: thanks for answering! unfortunately it doesnt work for me as my databases arent both oracle. I have one oracle and one postgres

Comment: I am just thinking, You could migrate all data result in another temporal table then you can join them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simple.

Install [oracle_fdw](https://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/) in the PostgreSQL database and define a foreign table for the Oracle table.

Then you can perform the join as if it were two PostgreSQL tables.

Be careful with big or complicated queries though: of course, the performance will be worse than for a join of two local tables.